# Binding a Grid ColumnDefinition width attribute to a Property is not working

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

This is the DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Node2Titles3Flds">
    <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1" Margin="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding myColumnWidth}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding id}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4,0,5,0" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Value}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
          </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is the property:

```
    public string myColumnWidth { get; set; }  //using Fody
```

The code compiles and runs.  The DataTemplate is in a ResourceDictionary that is visible to the property.

There are a couple of strange things happening:

- Intellisense does not display anything while typing 'mCol' in the DataTemplate.  Compilation has no affect.
- The Binding of myColumnWidth is not working at all.

The ResourceDictionary named ResDict.xaml is in the root folder and here is the link

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResDict.xaml">
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </Window.Resources>
```

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make your Property to be double, and set some value for it in DataContext(viewModel)

example:

```
  public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Width = 200;
        }
        public double Width { get; set; }
```

and in xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Width}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

and thats working just fine. If you want to adjust in in runtime, then your ViewModel need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and property will need to call OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Fixed the problem via redoing some portions of the resource dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem.  Went back and redid some items that weren't correct.  I would explain but ... it was too messy.